# Uninstall CUDA and all files

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I tried to install CUDA toolkit for Ubuntu 18.04 following [the instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal) on the site.

I wasn't aware it was going to try to install everything to my computer partition (which only had 17.6 GB free), but it did. Now my computer partition has 0B of free space left.

So my questions are:

1. How do I uninstall CUDA and all the files it downloaded to free up space on my installation partition?
2. How do I tell the CUDA installation to install it to another volume?

Comment: Which installation did you choose, the .run file or a deb file?

Comment: @ubfan1 oh, sorry, I chose the deb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing the installed deb file, just use:

```
sudo dpkg -P cudawhateverdebyouinstalled
```

For installing to another location, I used:

```
  dpkg-deb --extract yourcuda.deb directory-for-install
```

Then alter your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH as recommended to add the new bin and lib locations from your install location.  Test things out by compiling/running the cudasamples.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly the purge part did not work, I had to clean install Ubuntu to get rid of all the cuda files, but the installing to another location worked very well.